# Using “search” vs. “relatedTo” in a template

Tags: search, performance, relations

I have problems to understand the difference between search and relatedTo. From my understanding, this is a fulltext search on all fields.

```twig
{% set entries = craft.entries.search(test).order('score') %}
```

Does the following approach mean the same?

```twig
{% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(test).order('score').find() %}
```

And if yes, which one delivers the better performance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To be honest, those two parameters may seem to be slightly similar but provide a totally different functionality.

From their documentation on search:

> **search**
>
> Only fetch entries that match a given search query. (See Searching for the syntax and > available search attributes.)

Which means whatever you pass in `.search(query)`, and there is a rather complex list [here](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/searching), will actually 'search' Craft for the query string you specify.

On a different note,

> **relatedTo**
>
> Only fetch entries that are related to certain other elements. (See
> Relations for the syntax options.)

This on the other hand only 'relates' to other entries, meaning its not performing a fill search on Craft, only the entries. A detailed reference on relations can be found [here](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/relations).

As far as performance, the two are unrelated as it really depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Hope this clears it up for you!

Comment: Using search is going to be slower in about 99% of the cases as it's doing a MySQL Full Text Search (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html), an inherently slow operation.

Comment: Excellent point Brad.