# .relatedTo() not returning tags with spaces

Tags: relations, search, tags, slug, whitespace

I think I'm seeing a bug while using advanced search with `relatedTo()`. If I use a simple search, like this:

```
{% set param = {
   order: 'RAND()',
   limit: null,
   search: "#{request.tags}"
} %}
```

It finds a tag like `low confidence` without any issue. However, using the code I have below throws no errors, but returns no results:

```
{% set request = craft.request.getQuery() %}

{% set param = {
  order: 'RAND()',
  limit: null,
} %}

{% set param = craft.config.devMode or craft.config.staging
             ? param|merge({ group: 'testing' })
             : param|merge({ group: 'verified' }) %}

{% set relatedToParam = ['and'] %}

{% if request.tags %}
  {% set tagId = craft.tags.group('specialism').slug(request.tags).ids() %}
  {% set relatedToParam = relatedToParam|merge([{
    targetElement: tagId,
    field: 'tagsSpecialism',
  }]) %}
{% endif %}

{% if relatedToParam|length > 1 %}
    {% set param = param|merge({ relatedTo: relatedToParam }) %}
{% endif %}

{% set users = craft.users(param) %}
```

<s>I'm fairly confident it's not an issue with my code, as every other search combination is working.</s>

#### Update

This is expected behaviour and requires proper hyphenated `slug-path` to work properly with `.slug()` in my code sample. See answer below!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your working example, you’re mapping `request.tags` to the `search` param, but in the non-working example, you’re mapping it to the `slug` param.

Those two params are handled in very different ways. `search` will do some normalization routines on the value, and perform a very loose search for those keywords (see https://craftcms.com/docs/searching for more details). But the `slug` param will actually look for an exact match.

So if `request.tags` is set to `"low confidence"` and you pass that value into a `slug` param, I have *complete* confidence that it will return zero results, since `"low confidence"` isn’t actually a valid slug (see what I did there?).

You would have slightly better luck passing `request.tags` through the [kebab filter](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/filters#kebab), which will make the value look a little more like a valid slug. But the `search` param is probably a better bet unless you know for sure that `request.tags` is actually going to be a slug.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, I could add the kebab filter to the `{{ option.value }}` ... I guess there's a chance users could add odd characters as tags, but they'll be managed anyway. Performance wise, is `relatedTo` quicker than `search`? It's more specific using `relatedTo` but there are a few `and` conditions. Thanks Brandon!

Comment: It seems `search` might be slower according to [Brad's comment here](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1387/using-search-vs-relatedto-in-a-template#comment2230_1390)

Comment: @Rob Yeah search will be a bit slower due to the added complexity. If you can be sure you've got the right slug value to begin with, the relatedTo+slug route is better.

Comment: Cool, I'll do that. There's no [`tag.slug` on the docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.tags), I've changed to `<option value="{{ tag.title|kebab }}">` but is `tag.slug` an available option? It seems to work too.

Comment: @Rob Yes, tags have slugs. Will update the docs.