# Search entries AND within associated assets fields

Tags: assets, field, search, entries-field

I have a large list of entries. Each entry has a a bunch of fields and a file-field with one or two files. Those files have related field (Author, Date, ..).

I have now implemented a search. All things are working so far. However, the search does not include the asset's fields. Only the asset's title is recognized.

Can I somehow search in asset fields? I tried something like

```
field1: *query* AND files.author: *query*
```

but this does not work :(

I have read that I can search all assets that are related to that section, but I would like to include this query in one query than in two queries..

Comment: Just to be clear, your entry has an Assets field on it and in the Assets field layout, there are other fields (author and date)? Is author a Users field and Date a date/time field?

Comment: Yes. My entry has an assets field. The assets are restricted to a source that has some custom fields in its field layout. So each asset/file has a few basic plain text fields that I want to include in my search, nothing fancy, it's simply plain text.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this in one query. You could get the get the actual `author` field and do another search against that (and merge the results) or go the "relatedTo" route. See here for differences: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1387/using-search-vs-relatedto-in-a-template

Comment: I have one more idea.. Can I do something like a "JOIN" with mysql? Since **all** items contain at least one file, a collection could be _build_ with the file.author field included as a field on the same level as the entries field. Then this collection should be searchable. Is it possible to create such a collection with the content of the assets field as an entries field?

Answer (score 1):

I have now found a workaround using the information @brad-bell provided, that is working, but not exactly what I wanted:

```
{# Normal search #}
{% set resultsA = craft.entries(search_criteria).ids() %}

{# Assets search #}
{% set assets = craft.assets.customFieldName('*'~query~'*') %}
{% set resultsB = craft.entries.relatedTo({
        targetElement: assets,
        field: 'customFieldName'
    }).ids() | without(resultsA) %}

{# Merge results, paginate #}
{% set results = resultsA | merge(resultsB) %}
{% paginate results.limit(10) as pageInfo, pageEntries %}
```

How I did it:

1. Perform a **normal** search for entries containing the *query* in one of their fields (specified in search_criteria, not included in the code above) and **get the IDs** of the found entries.
2. Search for assets that contain the *query* in their *customField*. Since I'm only searching one field, I do not use the search-function, which would be an option when searching multiple fields.
3. Now I'm getting the entries that are related to the assets. As in step 1, I attain the IDs, ignoring IDs already present in the first set of results, to avoid duplicates *(which I found out late are not a problem, since `craft.entries` - in point 5 - only returns each entry once)*
4. I merge both arrays.
5. Get an *ElementCriteriaObject* containing all entries with the IDs collected before.
6. I paginate them as usual.

If you do not need to paginate, step 5-6 are might be unnecessary. You could simple use `find()` instead of `ids()` to get arrays which you then could merge. This however will cause duplicates!

### Although this code works, it has a few disadvantages:

- The results are **ordered by their position in both arrays**. *resultsA* are listed first, followed by *resultsB*. In my application I can live with that, since queries fetching many results in assets will usually fetch almost no results in entries and vice versa. I tried to **sort** and **order** them by the number of occurrences, however, this did not work using only twig functions. With the help of a simple plugin as host for some php array sorting, ordering of the results could be improved.
- **Performance** is not very good, since many queries are necessary.

### Idea

One idea in my mind was to build a custom MySQL-query, which JOINS the assets fields (combined to a string if there are multiple ones) to the entry's row. However, I was not able to accomplish that. If anyone knows how to do so: Let me know!

Thanks for your help!